# How do you add a child of a custom class to GameScene?

Tags: swift

I have a custom class named `Test` that extends SKShapeNode with 4 SKShapeNodes as its child, and I would like to add them as a child of GameScene. However, when I try to execute `addChild()` in GameScene, I end up getting the error `signal SIGABRT`.

In my custom class I declare:

```
let shapeR = SKShapeNode()
let shapeG = SKShapeNode()
let shapeY = SKShapeNode()
let shapeB = SKShapeNode()
```

Then in `override init()`, I call the `addChild()` methods:

```
addChild(shapeR)
addChild(shapeG)
addChild(shapeY)
addChild(shapeB)
```

Finally in GameScene, I iterate through the children with (`test` is defined as `Test()`):

```
for child in test.children {

    addChild(child)

}
```

How do I fix this?

Edit: I need 4 SKShapeNodes since I want 4 different colors in my custom SKShapeNode object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I just had to `addChild()` the entire class and not just separate `SKShapeNodes`

Comment: Good job. Mark it answered or delete!